# Using ELMAH with Areas in MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I'm following this blog post about setting up ELMAH with MVC:

http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/logging-on-mvc-part-1/

I've only done part 1. Everything works correctly if I simply go to the Home controller, and then cause an error. I can view /elmah.axd as well, and my errors are logging in the database correctly.

However, I've added an area to my application named Admin. If I navigate to /Admin, I receive the following error:

**System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.**

```
public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
{
    var controller = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName); //Error here

    var c = controller as Controller;
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with my Area.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT for jfar:**

For instance, I have an Employees controller in my Admin area:

```
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{
    private IEmployeesRepository employeesRepository;

    public EmployeesController(IEmployeesRepository employeesRepository)
    {
        this.employeesRepository = employeesRepository;
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your AdminController have a parameterless constructor?

---

Yes, you'll need to have a parameterless constructor.  If you are trying to inject dependencies you'll need to write or use a controller factory which knows how to do this.

This may help:

[Constructor Dependency Injection in a ASP.NET MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338271/constructor-dependency-injection-in-a-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm passing a repository to all my controller constructors. I've edited my original to show you an example. Do I just need to add a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm using the newest version of Ninject, in which my MvcApplication in global.asax inherits from NinjectHttpApplication. Do you know how I can override the NinjectControllerFactory in order to inject my dependencies to a parameterless constructor?